# Capture and parse output of Whateverable bots

Tags: raku, whateverable

Since that is the standard way to present output in the [Perl 6 documentation](https://docs.perl6.org), I'm using the [whateverable bots](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable) to evaluate expressions via the [#perl6 IRC channel](https://perl6.org/community/irc) or the `#whateverable` channel. Produced output is something like this:

```
 10:28:19   jmerelo | p6: say 333444777 ~~ /(3+)/                                                                                                           │
 10:28:19 evalable6 | jmerelo, rakudo-moar 5ce24929f: OUTPUT: «｢333｣␤ 0 => ｢333｣␤»
```

(in the WeeChat console program). From that output, I cut and paste to the document, erasing the parts I'm not interested in.

I was wondering if there was some easy way to parse and save that output directly, either server-based (some Whateverable bots save to gists, for instance), or client-based via scriptint the irssi or weechat platform.

Comment: Maybe perl6 documentation should provide a tool for writers that will automatically add OUTPUT comments to the doc files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the most convenient solution in this case would be to bypass irc bots and define a bash function. Something like this:

```sh
d6() { echo -n '# OUTPUT: «'; perl6 -e "$1" | sed -z 's/\n/␤/g'; echo '»'; }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```sh
d6 'say 42'
```

Which will produce this output:

```
# OUTPUT: «42␤»
```

Of course, you'd need a different solution for other operating systems.

As a bonus, you can also put it into the clipboard automatically:

```
d6 'say 42' | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)
```

Comment: That would work for evalable, but what about the rest of the bots?

Comment: @jjmerelo well, do you need that kind of formatting (docs oriented) for [other bots](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/wiki)? I don't think the output of any other bot should ever be put into the documentation. Even committable (which runs code on different *rakudo* revisions) is arguably not suitable for documentation because its output demonstrates implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: well, I might need it for tutorials, articles or even books. Benchable would be an interesting example, although this one already produces gists. It needn't be on the server, it could be a client-side script.